# Asteroid belt to earth orbit

Tags: propulsion, gravity, engines, trajectory

Given a constant 1g acceleration with a reaction-less drive how long would it take to achieve zero-zero in earth orbit from the asteroid belt?

Comment: Not enough information for a valid answer. The "asteroid belt" is a large zone, essentially a donut around the sun. Earth can occupy many places along it's own circular path depending on date. You might want to look for a range of possible times, or pick a belt object in particular to narrow it down.

Comment: What is "zero-zero"?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just want to be in the belt, and don't care about anything else.

The [asteroid belt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asteroid_belt) starts at 2.06 AU. We of course are at 1 AU. That means you have to cross about 148 million km. That distance could be covered one-way (No stopping) from a stop in 180,000 s, or just over 2 days. With stopping, that time becomes closer to 3 days. This is a reasonable approximation, as to do it for real one would have to include the Earth's orbital speed around the Sun, but that should be a small order affect, as the Earth isn't moving towards the asteroid belt for this direct encounter.

Of course, that distance could be as long as 4.28 AU, assuming you want to get to the furthest part of the belt from Earth. The time it takes would be about 3 days for a non-stop, or about 4.5 days for a rendezvous orbit.